# builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list. line 10, in <module> if generation[row][col] == 0:

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

My program is to Write a program that will simulate a network of computer that is infected with a virus at various spots.

Based off a list of random numbers 0 (healthy),1 (infected), and 2 (dead) my function needs to display a circle at the given position on the graphics window. Here is the code I have so far for the given function below.

```
def displaygen(generation,  win):        
    for row in generation:
        for col in row:
            position = Point(5,5)    
            if generation[row][col] == '0':
                circ = Circle(position,3)
                circ.setFill('green')
                circ.draw(win)
            elif generation[row][col] == '1':
                circ = Circle(position,3)
                circ.setFill('red')
            elif generation[row][col] == '2':
                circ = Circle(position,3)
                circ.setFill('black')
```

Comment: `for row in generation` gets you the *elements*, not their *indices*, so `generation[row]` won't work out.

Comment: yeah, replace your generation[row][col] with just col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop should iterate over the indices not the row (list) or just get the element in each column. When you access from the generation matrix (`generation[row][col]`), you use the row and indices which seem they should be int values, where in your for loop you access the row list.

Try the following:

```
def displaygen(generation,  win):        
    for row in range(len(generation)):
        for col in range(len(generation[row])):
            position = Point(5,5)    
            if generation[row][col] == '0':
                circ = Circle(position,3)
                circ.setFill('green')
                circ.draw(win)
            elif generation[row][col] == '1':
                circ = Circle(position,3)
                circ.setFill('red')
            elif generation[row][col] == '2':
                circ = Circle(position,3)
                circ.setFill('black')
```

or access the elements in the matrix directly

```
    def displaygen(generation,  win):        
        for row in generation:
            for col in row:
                position = Point(5,5)    
                if col == '0':
                    circ = Circle(position,3)
                    circ.setFill('green')
                    circ.draw(win)
                elif col == '1':
                    circ = Circle(position,3)
                    circ.setFill('red')
                elif col == '2':
                    circ = Circle(position,3)
                    circ.setFill('black')
```

Comment: Iterating over `range(len(` is rarely the Pythonic approach, particularly not when the OP doesn't actually need the indices.

Comment: I'm not convinced that he does or doesn't need the indices since his code could be only a related segment so I've answered with both. Thanks for the convention tip though.

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop, `col` is getting the actual value of each column (as opposed to the index). So you don't need to access the element using the `generation[row][col]` syntax, just use the element directly, like:

```
for row in generation:
    for col in row:
        if col == '0':
```